# jQuery When Then Done

Tags: jquery, ajax, .when

I am trying to validate a field off of two calls to the database. it goes to the database and validates if its true or false. I need to chain a few AJAX calls to do this. I am using `.when`, `.then`, and `.done` to do this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var Validate = function () {
        var isValid = true;
        $errorList.find('li').remove();
        $lblAError.text('');

        $.when(ParcelValidate(isValid))
            .then(AccountValidate(isValid))
            .done(function () {
            return isValid
        });
    };

    var ParcelValidate = function (isValid) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "../WebServices/ParcelMasterWebService.asmx/IsParcelActive",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "pin": $parcID.val() }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.d) {
                    isValid = false;
                    $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                    $errorList.append('<li>Parcel must be on record.</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                }
            },
            fail: function () {
                isValid = false;
                $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                $errorList.append('<li>Unexpected error occured!</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
            }
        })
    }
    var AccountValidate = function (isValid) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "../WebServices/FireProtectMasterWebService.asmx/isAccountActive",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "accountID": $parcID.val() }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d) {
                    isValid = false;
                    $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                    $errorList.append('<li>Cannot have duplicate Parcels.</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                }
            },
            fail: function () {
                isValid = false;
                $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                $errorList.append('<li>Unexpected error occured!</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Will you define "doesn't seem to be working?" What do you expect to happen, what happens instead, and what have you tried to fix it? What error messages do you see?

Comment: I need it to run one ajax call then the next. only after those have completed and ran the success or fail sections do I want it to return isValid to me. Right now it starts the ajax calls and just moves on and returns undefined and then the calls come back and have nothing to return to.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues, the first one is that the is that the validate function is not returning anything, since you are making asynchronous call your function should return a promise and instead of returning a boolean it would be better to reject/resolve this promise, your code would look like this:

```
var Validate = function () {
    $errorList.find('li').remove();
    $lblAError.text('');
    var promise = $.Deferred();

    ParcelValidate(promise).then(AccountValidate(promise));

    return promise;
};

var ParcelValidate = function (promise) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "../WebServices/ParcelMasterWebService.asmx/IsParcelActive",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "pin": $parcID.val() }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.d) {
                $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                $errorList.append('<li>Parcel must be on record.</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                promise.reject(false);
            }
        },
        fail: function () {
            $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
            $errorList.append('<li>Unexpected error occured!</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
            promise.reject(false);
        }
    })
}
var AccountValidate = function (promise) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "../WebServices/FireProtectMasterWebService.asmx/isAccountActive",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "accountID": $parcID.val() }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d) {
                $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                $errorList.append('<li>Cannot have duplicate Parcels.</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                promise.reject(false);
            }
            promise.resolve(true);
        },
        fail: function () {
            $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
            $errorList.append('<li>Unexpected error occured!</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
            promise.reject(false);
        }
    })
}
```

Now whatever is calling validate should wait for the promise and react accordingly to the done/fail methods ie:

```
Validate().done(function(){/*valid*/}).fail(function(){/*not valid*/})
```

One last thing as it is your code right now, since you are passing the isValid as a parameter, changing the value would not modify the isValid value of the original function.

Comment: Sorry I am not very good with this stuff. I've followed what you put down and it loops through it a few times but it still ends up returning before the ajax is finished. Now it just returns true instead of undefined. `$insert.click(function () {
            var isValid;

            if ($parcID.val() != "") {

                Validate().done(function (data) {
                    return data
                }).fail(function () {
                    return false
                })
            }            
        });` Here is what I have calling it. not sure where I'm wrong

Comment: Which ajax call is the one that is not waiting for?

Comment: Both it just kind of runs over the functions and goes straight back to the caller with out waiting on a response from anything.

Comment: Remember that all these functions are promise based and that they are async, so they are going to go straight back to the caller but will eventually trigger the done/fail functions. Basically you need to put all the caller logic inside the done/fail functions and if you need to return a value based on this calls on the caller, then the caller must return also a promise that will be resolved. Can you update your question on how it is right now and how are you calling it and the logic after calling it?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem I wanted to solve was that I wanted to reject a click event if I got true from one ajax call or false from another. The problem I was running into is that it would run all of them and go back to the event that started it and once I got the answer back from the server it would hit my returns but would not go back to the event. The event would already close with a value of true and run my other sections of code even if the answers I got back were false.

To fix this I added another button for them to click hid the asp control and had the new button run the validation. When I get a answer back from the ajax I validate what was returned and tell the JavaScript to click the asp control to fire the event. Not the most elegant or proper way but it works.

```
var Validate = function (Filter) {
    $errorList.find('li').remove();
    $lblAError.text('');
    var promise = $.Deferred();
    var hdnbtn = document.getElementById('btnInsert');

    $.when(ParcelValidate()).then(function (data) {
        if (data.d) {
            $.when(AccountValidate()).then(function (data2) {
                if (data2.d) {
                    $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                    $errorList.append('<li>Cannot have duplicate Parcels.</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                } else {
                    hdnbtn.click();
                }
            })
        }
        else {
                $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
                $errorList.append('<li>Parcel must be on record.</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
            }
    })
};

var ParcelValidate = function () {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "../WebServices/ParcelMasterWebService.asmx/IsParcelActive",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "pin": $parcID.val() }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'json',            
        fail: function () {
            $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
            $errorList.append('<li>Unexpected error occured!</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));
            //promise.fail(false);
        }
    })
};
var AccountValidate = function () {
   return  $.ajax({
        url: "../WebServices/FireProtectMasterWebService.asmx/isAccountActive",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "accountID": $parcID.val() }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'json',
        fail: function () {
            $lblPError.text('!').css(({ "color": "red" }));
            $errorList.append('<li>Unexpected error occured!</li>').css(({ "color": "red" }));                
        }
    })
}
```